# Submit form on click event with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Form.Submit function which does something and I want to call this function on a button click event.

My Form.Submit function is:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {

        // get all the inputs into an array.
        var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

        // get an associative array of objects.
        var values = {};

        $inputs.each(function() {
            values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });

        // Process Dates from form data Format Should be 2016-01-01T16:51:57.000+0000

        StartDate = values.datastartdate + "T" + values.datastarttime + ".000+0000";
        EndDate = values.dataenddate + "T" + values.dataendtime + ".000+0000";

        // Data to Submit
        var formData = {
            'db': values.db,
            'Start': StartDate.toString(),
            'End': EndDate.toString()
        };


        //Use Ajax to submit the form data
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/imagelist_data/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(result) {
                // ... Process the result ...
                //alert(formData.db + formData.Start + formData.End);
                alert(result);
                Newvalues = result;
            }

        });

        //$('#example').empty();
        table.ajax.reload( function ( json ) {
           Newvalues = json;
        });
});
```

My button click function:

```
$('#onebutton').click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
```

When I paste my Submit.Form Function inside the .click function it doesn't trigger the submit.form function.

Help Needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply trigger submit for form:

```
$('#onebutton').click(function () {
    $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
});
```

---

I think if you just simply put inner content of submit function to `.click` it should work, because you do so called *form hijacking*

Comment: Thanks alot. It did the Trick.. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `on()` and a `submit()` should work assuming the form action has the appropriate action:

```
$('#onebutton').on("click",function(e){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    //$('#myForm').submit();
 });
```